# Pulsar 220dtsi engine oil level

Tags: motorcycle, oil, pulsar

For my Pulsar 220, I started using Motul 5100 15W-50 engine oil. The last time I changed my engine oil, I used only 1 L, whereas the actual requirement prescribed is 1.2 L. It's been two weeks since I've changed the oil, is it ok for me to add 150 or 200 mL now? Is it ok to add new oil to already running oil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely okay to add the extra oil at any time. Add fresh to old oil whenever the vehicle (whatever type of vehicle) needs it. For best results, use the same brand & weight of oil you used in the first place. While not absolutely necessary, you'll avoid issues by doing so.

Ensure you double check the amount of oil which is in the motorcycle already and do not overfill it. If you overfill it, you run the risk of blowing out seals/gaskets, as well as risking internal damage if you put way too much in. A little over probably won't hurt anything, but really, just stay at the proper level and you should be golden.

Comment: What about the oil that might still be stuck inside inspite of removing it through the drain nut,there might be some oil still remaining inside right?And not all mechanics actually take effort to tilt it and release all the oil.so how to account for it?

Comment: The important thing is that you're between the max and min fill lines. Every bike will either have a sight window where you can see the oil level, or a dipstick where you can see a mark from the oil level. Don't worry so much about how much oil you put in, only that it's at the correct level. Also, make sure you're checking it as described in the owner's manual. The oil level can and will be drastically different when the bike is on it's sidestand, compared to when it's upright or on it's centre stand.